# Swapping UITableViews in a single UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have 1 view controller where depending on the button that is clicked, a view at the bottom is swapped between 4 different table views. These table views are in their own separate UITableViewController's in the storyboard. I add the tableViews like this:

```
Tracks_TVC *tracksTVC = [[Tracks_TVC alloc] init];
tracksTVC.view.frame = _postView.frame;
tracksTVC.view.tag = kTagPostView;
[self.view addSubview:tracksTVC.view];
```

I get this error message when the code is run:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource
>   must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

I've implemented the data source in the separate UITableViewController's properly (I believe so) with all the required methods so I'm confused as to why I'm receiving this error. My only thought is that the added table view isn't using the methods in it's own UITableViewController..? Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try to force fully assign data source and delegates like this
`tracksTVC.tableView.dataSource = tracksTVC;`
`tracksTVC.tableView.delegate = tracksTVC;`. May this help

Comment: If you have them in storyboard, then you need to instantiate them from storyboard and not simply the class. Because I assume, you set it's delegate and datasource in storyboard and also the cells. The way you try to create the tableview in code, you would need to set the datasource and delegate and register the cells in init.

Comment: Get one table working, then add the others one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the property of TableViewController such as -

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) Tracks_TVC *tracksTVC;
```

Now in viewDidLoad initialise the same -

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   self.tracksTVC = [[Tracks_TVC alloc] init];

   self.tracksTVC.view.frame = _postView.frame;

   self.tracksTVC.view.tag = kTagPostView;

   [self.view addSubview:self.tracksTVC.view];

}
```

Note : Also make sure that you are returning the cell in Data source.